# How to pivot 2 columns in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have a dataframe as below and I need to pivot it such that two new columns are created with the values "var1" and "var2" taken from the column headers as "var3" and then with the amount associated with each as "var4", grouped by id. There are other columns in the dataframe I am working with, but they are all at the same level of id.

| id | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 465 | 1000 | 200 |
| 455 | 2000 | 400 |

The resulting output would be:

| id | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 465 | var1 | 1000 |
| 465 | var2 | 200 |
| 455 | var1 | 2000 |
| 455 | var2 | 400 |

Comment: You can use [`melt`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars=['id'], value_vars=['var1', 'var2'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [unpivot](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-pivot-and-unpivot-dataframe/#unpivot-dataframe):

```
df.unpivot(['id'], ['var1', 'var2'], 'var3', 'var4').show()
```

Or [stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.selectExpr("id", "stack(2, 'var1', var1, 'var2', var2) as (var3, var4)").show()
```

Or [melt](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df.melt(ids=['id'], values=['var1', 'var2'],variableColumnName="var3",valueColumnName="var4").show()
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]